# android 2-dimensional hashmap key

Tags: android, hashmap

I want to create a hashmap of objects and use a 2-dimensional key:

```
public HashMap<ConversationKey, ConversationItem> ConversationMap = new HashMap<ConversationKey, ConversationItem>();
```

where a conversation key is:

```
public class ConversationKey {

private String Left;
private String Right;

}
```

but i don't completely understand what ovverridded methods I need, another post said I need a hashcode() and equals() but hashcode() is unavailable and automatically adding unimplemented methods just adds compareTo()

Can someone help me make a 2d key object to be used to retrieve items from a hashmap by supplying two string values as the key?

here is what I have so far:

```
  public class ConversationKey implements Comparable<ConversationKey> {

private String Left;
private String Right;

public ConversationKey(String left, String right) {

    Left = left;
    Right = right;
}

@Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof ConversationKey) {
            return Left.equals(((ConversationKey)obj).Left) &&
                    Right.equals(((ConversationKey)obj).Right);
        }
        return false;
    }

@Override
public int compareTo(ConversationKey another) {

    if (Left.equals(another.Left) && Right.equals(another.Right)) {
        return 0;
    }

    return -1;
}

}
```

The end implementation being:

```
 ConversationKey ck = new ConversationKey("jack", "jane");
 ConversationItem Conversation1 = ConversationMap.get(ck);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for Comparable you need to use

```
 public int compareTo(ConversationKey  ck){}
```

Comment: That's what I can't seem to get to work, also there is another type called a Comparator - not sure which to try to implement

Comment: comparable is used for objects that you want to compare(that makes them comparable).Comparator is a class that compares objects by overriding relevant methods.Comparator may be used for eg. with collections.sort("your comparator class object here")